# Multi-line *non* match with attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I was playing around with parsing (PostgreSQL) logs which can have entries that are multi-line.

```
2016-01-01 01:01:01 entry1
2016-01-01 01:01:02 entry2a
    entry2b
2016-01-01 01:01:03 entry3
```

So - with a Perl or Python script I'd just grab the next line and if it wasn't starting with a timestamp append it to the previous log entry. What is a sensible way to approach this with `attoparsec` hooked up to `io-streams`? I clearly want to do something with `lookAhead` and failing to match a timestamp but my brain is just missing something.

---

Nope - still can't see it. I've stripped back what I've got. Parsing a single line is easy. I can't figure out how to parse "up to" another parsing pattern - I can see a lookAhead function I can use, but I don't see how that fits in with applying a "not" condition.

I can't see how I can match  either. Entirely possible my brain has seized up.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module DummyParser (
    LogStatement (..), parseLogLine
    -- and, so we can test it...
    , LogTimestamp , parseTimestamp
    , parseSqlStmt
    , newLineAndTimestamp
) where

{-  we want to parse...
TIME001 statement: SELECT true;
TIME002 statement: SELECT 'b',
  'c';
TIME003 statement: SELECT 3;
-}

import           Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8            as B

type LogTimestamp = Int

data LogStatement = LogStatement {
     l_ts  :: LogTimestamp
    ,l_sql :: String
} deriving (Eq, Show)


restOfLine :: Parser B.ByteString
restOfLine = do
    rest <- takeTill (== '\n')
    isEOF <- atEnd
    if isEOF then
        return rest
    else
        (char '\n') >> return rest


-- e.g. TIME001
parseTimestamp :: Parser LogTimestamp
parseTimestamp  = do
  string "TIME"
  digits  <- count 3 digit
  return (read digits)


-- e.g. statement: SELECT 1
parseSqlStmt :: Parser String
parseSqlStmt = do
    string "statement: "
    -- How can I match until the next timestamp?
    sql <- restOfLine
    return (B.unpack sql)


newLineAndTimestamp :: Parser LogTimestamp
newLineAndTimestamp = (char '\n') *> parseTimestamp


spaces :: Parser ()
spaces = do
    skipWhile (== ' ')


-- e.g. TIME001 statement: SELECT * FROM schema.table;
parseLogLine :: Parser LogStatement
parseLogLine = do
    log_ts <- parseTimestamp
    spaces
    log_sql <- parseSqlStmt
    let ls = LogStatement log_ts log_sql
    return ls
```

---

EDIT: So, this was what I finally ended up with thank's to arrowd's help

```
isTimestampNext = lookAhead parseTimestamp *> pure()

parseLogLine :: Parser LogStatement
parseLogLine = do
    log_ts <- parseTimestamp
    spaces
    log_sql <- parseSqlStmt
    extraLines <- manyTill restOfLine (endOfInput <|> isTimestampNext)
    let ls = LogStatement log_ts (log_sql ++ (B.unpack $ B.concat extraLines))
    return ls
```

Comment: I don't think you need lookahead for this. Just parse the log times apart by matching on time stamps, and only _within_ each time-entry parse the sub-entries.

Comment: Hmm - I think I see what you mean. I've been thinking about it in a line-oriented way. If I make my delimiter "\n<timestamp>" we might sidestep the issue altogether. Thanks - I'll try it this evening if I get a chance.

Comment: Doesn't seem too complicated with `attoparsec`, but you should post your attempt so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combinator I shared on many attoparsec questions:

```
notFollowedBy p = p >> fail "not followed by"
```

Your solution would be something like

```
parseLogLine :: Parser LogStatement
parseLogLine = do
    log_ts <- parseTimestamp
    spaces
    log_sql <- parseSqlStmt
    newlineLeftover <- ((notFollowedBy parseTimestamp) *> parseSqlStmt) <|> pure ""
    let ls = LogStatement log_ts (log_sql ++ newlineLeftover
    return ls
```

The right hand of `*>` for `newlineLeftOver` expression would need some more work, i guess, but overall idea is like that.

Comment: Thanks. The twin ideas of thinking about failure and `*>` to provide a desired return value got it to click for me.