# Matching values that carry onto multiple following lines with attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I'm trying to parse the following:

```
message: 123 test
abc xys
messageA: hmm
messageA: testing
messageB: aueo
qkhwueoaz
```

Into something like:

```
[
  ("message", "123 test\nabcxyz"),
, ("messageA", "hmm")
, ("messageA","testing")
, ("messageB","aueo\nqkhwueoaz")
]
```

However I just can't seem to figure this out, I'm finding some difficulty in that I'm not 100% familiar with attoparsecs functionality (and I can't really see each function being documented as to whether it moves the cursor forward...).

I've read through: [Multi-line *non* match with attoparsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358797/multi-line-non-match-with-attoparsec) and I've got the following code:

```
isChrisNext :: Parser ()
isChrisNext = lookAhead (parseChris) *> pure()

notFollowedBy :: Monad m => m a -> m b
notFollowedBy p = p >> fail "not followed by"

restOfLine :: Parser Text
restOfLine = do
    rest <- takeTill (== '\n')
    isEOF <- atEnd
    if isEOF then
        return rest
    else
        (char '\n') >> return rest

parseChris :: Parser [Text]
parseChris = do
  x <- takeWhile1 (notInClass ":")
  _ <- string ":"
  x' <- manyTill restOfLine (endOfInput <|> isChrisNext)
  () <- return $ unsafePerformIO $! do
    print "?????????????"
    print x
    print x'
  return $ x : x'
```

However trying to parse the data with `parseChris` just returns:
`[ "message" ]` while I'm expecting `("message", "123 test\nabcxyz")`.

If I change the lookahead function to:

```
isChrisNext :: Parser ()
isChrisNext = lookAhead (string "message:") *> pure()
```

I get a more intended output of:

```
[ "message"
, "123 test"
, "abc xys"         
]
```

---

In addition, the question mentioned earlier also has a comment suggesting an approach of:

> Just parse the log times apart by matching on time stamps, and only
>   within each time-entry parse the sub-entries.

**I'm also aware of a potential issue where a second line could contain a `:`, but this is not something I need to take into consideration thankfully...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I find really useful when working with parser combinators is to break down the whole problem into smaller pieces. So, I'd just compose the parser bottom-up: a `keyValuePair` first, and then the whole parser consisting just of `many keyValuePair`s. The `keyValuePair` consumes the part before `:`  and then just eats as many lines without `:` as it can.

In code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as AT
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor

valuePart :: AT.Parser BS.ByteString
valuePart = AT.takeTill (`BS.elem` ":\n") <* AT.endOfLine

keyValuePair :: AT.Parser (BS.ByteString, BS.ByteString)
keyValuePair = do
    key <- AT.takeTill (== ':')
    void ": "
    valLines <- AT.many1 valuePart
    pure (key, BS.intercalate "\n" valLines)

parser :: AT.Parser [(BS.ByteString, BS.ByteString)]
parser = many keyValuePair
```

Running on your input data produces

```
*Main> AT.parseOnly parser test
Right [("message","123 test\nabc xys"),("messageA","hmm"),("messageA","testing"),("messageB","aueo")]
```

Note there is no lookahead, as there is no need for it: as soon as `valuePart` encounters a `:`, it just fails, which causes `keyValuePair` to stop and the next `keyValuePair` to get run by the top-level `many` in `parser`.

BTW you can use `trace` and `traceShow` from `Debug.Trace` instead of `unsafePerformIO` to produce debugging output.

Comment: Thanks, the note about how it actually works was really useful!